# Best way to call a JavaScript script after the HTML body loads with no JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I have a somewhat large .js file that is currently called in the header of a HTML     page, but it fails to execute because the elements have not loaded when the script is called. What is the best way to implement this? I've tried adding

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, false);
```

to the script but that doesn't seem to work. Calling the script in the footer or inline is not an option, nor is JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried `window.onload` ?

Comment: I've heard of that, but I have no idea how to implement it. I want to load the entire .js file, not just call a specific function as there are event handlers that are required for it to function. I may be misunderstanding how it works though.

This is my first time trying to use JavaScript in the head of a page, I've only used inline calls before.

Comment: Try something like `window.onload=function(){//Now create and append the script tag.}` You can use something like this to create the script tag... `var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "www.example.com/myscript.js";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);`

Comment: Where exactly would I put that in my .js or .html files?

Comment: in your `.html` file... The one you want to link the javascript to.

Answer (score 0):

Meet [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.
>
> There are also Gecko-Specific DOM Events like DOMContentLoaded and
>   DOMFrameContentLoaded (which can be handled using
>   EventTarget.addEventListener()) which are fired after the DOM for the
>   page has been constructed, but do not wait for other resources to
>   finish loading.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly how to use that. In the example no .js file is referenced.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do in the load event. `DOMContentLoaded` only waits for the HTML to finish writing. `onload` waits for all resources (images, scripts, etc.) to download first.

Comment: I guess I'd want the load() function to trigger so my event handlers are initialized, but I also have variables that reference elements in the page that obviously aren't finding those elements.

Comment: Chrome's inspect is still picking up an error when I try to initialize my event handler, says it references null.

Comment: Take a look at the Examples section. You could simply call `window.onload = load`.

Comment: Your problem may be in the load function itself then. Post your code for that.

Comment: `function load(){

 var calcButton = document.getElementById("calc");

 calcButton.addEventListener("click", calcPay, false);
 }`